# Testing file links in Capybara (or anything else that might work)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, selenium, capybara

I want to be able to insure a clicked link redirects to the right file.

I **don't** care what happens when a link directs to a file (open in a window, prompt for donwload, etc. etc). That's browser stuff, not web stuff.

I **do** want to know if the path resolves to the correct target - for example, the links with href "/getfiles/1" actually leads to, say, "this_is_a_picture.jpg", not "error.html" or "fallback_picture.jpg"

How can I do this?

Comment: Does the action render the file or redirect to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
page.should have_link 'Your Link', :href => example_path(:params => :must_be_exact)
```

This does not have a very good failure message.  Something like, "Expected link 'Your Link' to return something."  It means it cannot find that exact link, whether the text is there or not.

So...

```
page.should have_link 'View Picture', :href => picture_path(@picture)
```

should suffice. To test whether picture/1 points to this_is_a_picture.jpg or error.html is a controller test.